# Get Store Number in Module Magento 2 Compilation Error

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get the store number using a module the correct way and am having a bit of difficulty. I have used the below code which works however when trying to compile i recieve an error. My code is currently as below:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $_storeInfo;
protected $_storeManagerInterface;


public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data); 
    $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
    $this->_storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
}
public function getPhoneNumber()
{
    return $this->_storeInfo->getStoreInformationObject($this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore(null))->getPhone();
}
}
```

This appears to work fine and number is shown on front-end as expected. However upon running 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' the following errors are shown and compilation fails.

```
Incorrect dependency in class Vendor\Module\Block\Storenumber
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface already exists in context object
```

I can see that the storeManager interface is already called within \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template however removing this from construct also does not work. How do i correctly call the store number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep below code in your **__construct()** method of Block PHP file,

Already **Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context** file contains **Storemanager defination** so you have to use those method as directly from **$context object.**

```
public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data); 
    $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
    $this->_storeManagerInterface = $context->getStoreManager();;
}
```

Remove var folder and check again.

Comment: I think ive just got it working anyway by removing the store manager and using the original $this->_storeManager rather than $this->_storeManagerInterface

Comment: This is the correct way to define your storemanager in constuct() method when you have extends Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 method

Comment: Is this basically renaming the instance of the Storemanager to storemanagerinterface? Similar to what i just did but other way around?